# Use AWK and SED to read a sensor, and output value to html file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, openwrt

I have a TP-Link WR703N flashed with openWRT, connected to a one wire DS18B20 temperature sensor. My goal is to get the router to show the current temp. on a web page. I am using digitemp to read the sensor

When i issue the following command:

> root@OpenWrt:~# digitemp_DS9097 -a

The reply from digitemp is:

> DigiTemp v3.5.0 Copyright 1996-2007 by Brian C. Lane 
>   GNU Public License v2.0 - http://www.digitemp.com 
>   Feb 23 02:46:31 Sensor 0 C: 25.44 F: 77.79

I found [this example](http://haklabos.wordpress.com/projekti/digitemp/), where a CRON-script with AWK and SED is used to read the c value, and update a HTML-file.

When i try to paste the script to /etc/crontabs/root, some of the qoutation marks are replaced with ... in the VI editor. I tried to use the Nano editor instead, but it just replaces the qoutation marks with ^?^?^. I do not understand AWK as well as I wish, so i have trouble figuring outh wether the author of the script has used wrong qoutation-marks, or if there is another reason me not being able to input the right characters.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the formatting of that blog post, it's got non-ASCII quotes. Just edit them to fix.

```
*/1 * * * * TEMP=$(digitemp_DS9097 -a | grep -i sensor | awk '{print $7}'); sed -i -r "14s,>[^<]*</,>${TEMP}</," /www/index.html
```

I'm not sure if the rest of the line is right though, my sed doesn't have that -r flag, and the script tries to change line 14 (hence 14s...) which is very picky on whether you copied the html from the blog exactly. I used this instead:

```
*/1 * * * * TEMP=$(digitemp_DS9097 -a |grep -i sensor | awk '{print $7}');sed -i.bak "s,\\(66cc00.*\">\\)[^<]*</,\\1$TEMP</,"  /www/index.html
```

which matches on the colour number on the line instead. The extra `\\(...\\)` are capturing that so that I can use it again in the replacement as `\\1`.

I've just read the manual for `digitemp_DS9097` (http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/digitemp_DS9097/) - you'd be better running it as `digitemp_DS9097 -q -t 0 -O"%.2C"`, which gives you the output directly as a single Centigrade number with no need for grep/awk. eg:

```
*/1 * * * * TEMP=$(digitemp_DS9097 -q -t 0 -O"%.2C");sed -i.bak "s,\\(66cc00.*\">\\)[^<]*</,\\1$TEMP</,"  /www/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will try it out tomorrow, and come back to verfify that worked. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Sure. If you're still stuck with it, just ask.

Comment: It works great, thanks. I had to change the -O to lower case -o, and remove ".bak", and then your last line worked as intended.